# how to get last row in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using below code and formula gets filled in whole column instead of last row. data is available in A2:B4. I am getting 0 from C5 to C1000.

```
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  ss.getRange("C2").setFormula("A2*B2");

  var lr=ss.getLastRow();

  var fill = ss.getRange(2, 3,lr-1);

  ss.getRange("C2").copyTo(fill);

  Logger.log(lr);
```

Comment: Share your sheet.

Comment: I tried it and your code works perfectly. what is the problem? if you can share your sheet. There is some other problem.

Comment: Hi. I'm wondering if you resolved your problem, or whether you're still looking for assistance.